# Add the ability to exclude sites in global searches

Tags: feature-request, search, stackexchange.com, global-search

I would like to be able to search all sites in the SE network **except** for some sites. In my case, I want to remove the thousands of results from SO on a popular project for devs so I can see the handful of results on other sites from admins and users.

The current form only allows all sites or listed sites.

The answer linked does not tell me how to use the information in the answer. It is a poor answer for an average user.

As @Laurel described in a comment below, the [answer in a previously-proposed duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/174614/) (now deleted with that question being closed as a duplicate of this one) no longer works.

Comment: Answer there is horrifically out of date. Removed.

Comment: @Shog9 The question is a duplicate, however.

Comment: It's not, but I have better things to do than argue about it so we'll do it this way so there's at least a feature-request.