# Search Stack Exchange, but exclude groups?

Tags: support, search

Is there a way to search Stack Exchange for a keyword, but exclude specific discussion groups that I know don't have anything to do with what I am looking for?

- Search keyword: engineering
- Exclude: Stack Overflow, Ask Ubuntu, Server Fault, Super User

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Don't include SE site in SE search filter?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316399/dont-include-se-site-in-se-search-filter)

Answer (score 3):

For the specific example you gave there is a solution.

You could use google and do the following search:

```
"engineering" site:*.stackexchange.com
```

This works because the sites you want to exclude all have their own domains. Downsides are that you will also find results on for example blog.stackexchange.com and that this returns 547K results, so probably this isn't a really useful query.

In general you could exclude a certain site from your google search results by typing `-site:excludedsite.com`