# Please have same background color for indented code and inline code

Tags: feature-request, design, code-formatting, code-block, inline-code

In [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359133/search-stack-exchange-but-exclude-groups/359141#359141) I included both indented code, and an inline codeblock. 
 (Yes you may blame me for abusing code make-up for something that isn't technically code)

They both have a different shade of gray as background colour. See the image below:

[image]

Can we make them play nicely together and have them have the same background colour?

Comment: This has also been reported as an answer here: [New post formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353565/289905), and on MSO: [Background color of inline code should match background color of code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401623/4642212).

Comment: Yay for excellent search capabilities of SE @user289905. I'll leave the question for now, as I don't have much hope that an answer on that post will still be acted upon.

Comment: It was more remembering where to find these reports rather than finding them through search.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New post formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353446/new-post-formatting)

Comment: @bad_coder no it doesn't. It was reported as a bug in this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353550/361484) but never resolved. As that post is no longer followed by staff it is perfectly reasonable to have a separate feature request for this to be changed.