# Add option 'exclude these sites' in a filter rule

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-filters, filtering

This feature request is not a duplicate of
[Add the ability to exclude sites in global searches](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316399/dont-include-se-site-in-se-search-filter#comment1296258_388751). Please, note the **URLs in the quotations below are different**. That question is asking for the ability to exclude sites in global searches, **this one asks for the same ability, but in the filter rule page** (which is different).

Click the tags [global-search](/questions/tagged/global-search) [tag-filters](/questions/tagged/tag-filters) to see the difference on your own.

- Quoting the [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316399/dont-include-se-site-in-se-search-filter#comment1296258_388751) from my deleted answer there:

> This doesn't answer the question. The question is about using the **global search** feature, which is available at stackexchange.com not in the child sites. I just added [global-search](/questions/tagged/global-search) (to the question's tags)

- That question is about [global-search](/questions/tagged/global-search)

> This is the webpage/system that searches *all* Stack Exchange sites at once. It's found at **https://stackexchange.com/search**.

- This question is about [tag-filters](/questions/tagged/tag-filters)

> Tag filters (AKA the Stack Exchange™ GlobalTag MegaBlender™), as seen at **https://stackexchange.com/filters**.

---

When you create a filter by a tag at **https://stackexchange.com/filters** you can include either all sites, or create a list of allowed sites

- All Sites
- Just these sites: ...

**Add the third option to create a list of denied (excluded) sites**

- All sites except these sites: ...

This option is necessary because there are significant differences in the definitions of [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics) among the sites. For example,

- Tag [unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unix) at StackOverflow:

> NOTICE: All Unix questions must be related to programming; those that aren't will be closed. Use this tag only if your question relates to programming using Unix APIs or Unix-specific behavior, not just because you happen to run your code on Unix. General software issues should be directed to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange or to Super User.

Synonyms: unix-programming, unix-utils

- Tag [unix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix) at AskDifferent:

> UNIX is both the underlying code and architecture that makes up Mac OS X / iOS as well as a way of interacting with a Mac using the terminal app, X11 app, and various shells like `bash` or `zsh`. Whether you're logging into a mac using `ssh`, using `mdfind` or `tmutil` or using other open source software, you are doing things very much in common with other UNIX operating systems and toolsets such as Linux, GNU, and many, many others too numerous to list.

Synonyms: freebsd, bsd, linux, ubuntu

**As a result, for example, searching the tag *`ubuntu`* on all sites will result in including *AskDifferent* questions tagged *unix*! This is valid for all synonyms: *`freebsd, bsd, linux, ubuntu`*! This is absurd!**

- The sites shall have the right to define their tags.
- The users shall have the right to selectively ignore sites.

---

Examples

When you create [filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/) rule: *'Just questions tagged with the `ubuntu` tag on `All sites`'* the results will include `Ask Different` questions below because all of them are tagged [unix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix). You'll get the same results for any of the synonyms: *`freebsd, bsd, linux, ubuntu`*

- [how to let `clear` command just clears the current screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/459137/how-to-let-clear-command-just-clears-the-current-screen)

> I use iTerm2 apps as my terminal option on my Mac computers. On my 1st Mac, when I type clear, it just clears out the current screen, and when I scroll up, it could still show the previous contents on this tab which I really like. ...

[iTerm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITerm2)  is a macOS application. It has nothing to do either with BSD or Linux. But, it is tagged `unix`. This makes the question synonym with `freebsd, bsd, linux, ubuntu`.

**There are ~1000 questions on [AskDifferent tagged [unix]](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix) polluting `freebsd, bsd, linux, ubuntu` filters.**

When you [complain](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4208/on-ask-different-freebsd-is-a-synonym-of-unix) you'll learn from the moderator that [quoting](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4209/296767):

> ... having freebsd, linux and some other commonly used terms as synonyms of unix helps to keep the more "unixly" questions together, without getting lost in details. ... having too many detailed tags is more harmful than useful.